# Doctrine2's preUpdate missing PreUpdateEventArgs argument in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine2 documentation on `preUpdate` event [says](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html#preupdate)

> This event has a powerful feature however, it is executed with a `PreUpdateEventArgs` instance, which contains a reference to the computed change-set of this entity. This means you have access to all the fields that have changed for this entity with their old and new value.

Sounds useful! So what I do:

```
/**
 * Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Article
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Article
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if ( /* use $eventArgs here */ )

            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    // ...
}
```

But no luck - no arguments are passed:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   `Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Article::preUpdate()` must be an instance of
>   `Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs`, **none given**, called in
>   `...\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo.php` on line 1540 and defined in `...\src\Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Article.php` line 163

I guess this must work some other way in Symfony2. How do I do it?

Comment: I had similar problem and what I realized (after 4 hours) is that  Doctrine starting with version `2.4` starts passing `LifecycleEventArgs` to the lifecycle annotated method. So check your dependencies. Here's link to the original issue: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2186

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of handling lifecycle events.

First is simply annotate a method of your doctrine entity as @ORM\PreUpdate. This method will be called before update. The second is more complicated. It involves listener
`preUpdate`. It's a separate class that you subscribe to listen to particular events.

Read carefully from [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html#listening-to-lifecycle-events) again and the symfony [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).

Comment: I know that option exists but I thought I could receive the argument also with the annotation. Where would I set the event listener in Symfony? Because if I have to set it inside the controller, I can simply do the same work right away without using the event listeners at all. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can't get the argument with the annotation. I updated my answer with the symfony cookbook link that explains how to register your own listener.

Comment: That's a pity, makes the system more complicated. Thanks for your help, I'll dive into event listeners!

Comment: @Czechnology But it makes sense if you think about it, because you can use more than one annotation on a lifecycle callback (like `@ORM\PreUpdate` and `@ORM\PreFlush`) which both have different arguments and thus can't be combined in one function.

Answer (score 17):

You should remember what with PreUpdateEventArgs instance you have access to all the fields that have CHANGED for this entity with their old and new value. But in you example updatedAt will not be at that changeset. If you try to set updatedAt value, you should get error: "Field 'updatedAt' is not a valid field of the entity". So, you can change updateAt field and then use UnitOfWork:recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet. Example:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    if ($entity instanceof Product)
    {
        $entity->setDiscount(123);

        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(
            $em->getClassMetadata("XXXBundle:Product"),
            $entity
         );
    }
}
```

More code examples in my blog post (on russain:)): [Update doctine entity in preUpdate event](http://ruslanix.com/it-blog/doctrine-event-preupdate/)

Comment: When I try this method and try to persist a new entity I get the Doctrine error "Entity <classname> is not managed. An entity is managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through EntityManager#persist". Is there a way for this to work with new entities?

Comment: @DaveLancea Try the `prePersist` event. It's called before a new entity is persisted to the DB. See: [Doctrine Documentation: "Events - prePersist"](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#prepersist)

Comment: By the way, getClassMetadata is marked as Internal Only, do you have another way do get them ?