# Symfony2 Doctrine 'preUpdate' event to encode password

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Based on question and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824990/3198318), i confuesd what the event `preUpdate()` in combination with symfony and doctrine really does.

To be exact, i mean this line in the answer above:

`$event->setNewValue('password', $user->getPassword());`

Why i need the extra step of manually setting the new value?
I thought that doctrine handles the event and update the entity by itself without a call of e.g. `flush`?

Supportive of the thrown exception
`Field "password" is not a valid field of the entity "...\UserBundle\Entity\User" in PreUpdateEventArgs.`
when i use this, i don't understand why i need to modify the entity manually.

Extended info about the exception: it's only thrown when users logged in. Not when users are registered or edited.

Comment: Do you really have `password` property in `...\UserBundle\Entity\User` Entity with `getPassword()` and `setPassword()` methods?

Comment: Maybe you use any validators for this field? And that password what you set isn't valid? Check this, please

Comment: Yes @Victor i checked the properties and methods several times.
`
...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
 protected $password;

...
`
Also no validators for this.

Comment: What about direct password? Try to pass it directle like `$event->setNewValue('password', 'qwerty123');`. Is it work?

Comment: No, it don't works too. But the major question is, why i need this anyway? Maybe the exception is thrown because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10935362), but i still don't understand why i need to setting the value manually. @Victor

Comment: Check out a related answer and question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140815/doctrine2s-preupdate-missing-preupdateeventargs-argument-in-symfony2/10935362#10935362

Answer (score 2):

The `setNewValue()` method can be used to change the value of fields that have been marked as updated. It doesn't work if, for whatever reason, the field you want to update isn't already changed.

Usually, setting the password to null is enough to add it to the changeset. In the event that it isn't, you can request the unit of work recompute the changes.

For example:

```
<?php

if ($event->hasChangedField('password')) {
    $event->setNewValue('password', $newPassword);
}
else {
    $em = $event->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(
        $em->getClassMetadata(User::class),
        $entity
    );
}
```